# Python dictionary not updated across different files

Tags: python, variables, global

I have two files

1. `runner.py` - main

```
import secondthread
my_dict = {}

def action1():
    my_dict["i"] = 2

if __name__ == "__main__":
    action1()
    secondthread.action2()
```

2. `secondthread.py`

```
import runner

def action2():
    try:
        print("Thread2: dict value is = {}".format(runner.my_dict["i"]))
    except Exception as e:
        print("Thread2: dict haven't got updated value, len of dict is: {}".format(len(runner.my_dict)))
```

I am unsure why despite sequentially running `action1` then `action2` does not update the dictionary with the new key-value pair.

I have tried setting `my_dict` as a global variable in `secondthread.py` and it does not work. I understand that perhaps the circular dependency (`runner.py` depends on `secondthread.py` and `secondthread.py` depends on `runner.py` may be problematic, but I am not sure how else to read `my_dict` from `secondthread.py`).

Update1:
I have also tried inside `secondthread.py` which still results in the same error.

```
from runner import my_dict
```

Wouldn't this method already retrieve `my_dict` from global namespace?

Answer (score 2):

I think the crux of the problem is that due to the circular import, `runner` gets imported a second time. Importing a module will cause its code to run, thus `my_dict` will get initialized again, which you don't want. Code that depends on the ordering or frequency of module imports is problematic.

The recommended way to solve this kind of problem is to move the variable initializations to a single module, which is then imported once from each file: https://docs.python.org/3/faq/programming.html#how-do-i-share-global-variables-across-modules
In your case, you would create a third file, say `init_vars.py` and import it from both `runner.py` and `secondthread.py`.

Comment: Nearly. If you import a module twice, it will be run only once and then cached. But in this case we have an other specialty of Python: The module you are starting becomes the `__main__` module and that is how it will be named internally. If you have a circular import back to this module it will be run a 2nd time and this second instance will be named by the actual name of the module, here `runner`. So, there are two versions of it in memory `__main__` and `runner`. And both have their own `my_dict`.

Comment: @KlausD I guess you're explaining why the import happens twice in this setup? Maybe you should elaborate this into another answer.

Comment: Agree with @klaus-d, replace my_dict["i"] = 2 with secondthread.runner.my_dict["i"] = 2
It'll work. print - id(my_dict) - in both files - both have different references due to this import problem mentioned.

Comment: @KlausD Could you please elaborate more on what happens to the `__main__` of the second instance (`secondthread.py`) given that the first instance (`runner.py`) has been run and cached? Correct me if I'm wrong, but as long as a single `__main__` is run sequentially then a consistent view of the same `my_dict` should be observed for whichever `__main__` instance it is in?